# Meaning of 勝つ手に

Tags: set-phrases

Dad is being told off for eating too fast and not leaving enough food for grandma and grandad. He replies:

> 「おう、これでも遠慮してるんだぞ。じいさんもばあさんも、どんどん勝つ手に食べりゃいいんだ。」
>   Even though it looks (bad) I'm holding back. Both grandma and grandad rapidly ????

I assume 食べりゃ is a contraction of 食べれば. "It's okay if grandma and grandad eat ...".

I can't understand the 勝つ手に part. I guess from the に that 勝つ手に is supposed to be an adverb but I can't make anything make sense that fits the context.

Comment: By the way, `勝つ手` (katsute) means winning hand (in game), but in this context, it seems to be `勝手` as the answer below suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be [勝手{かって}](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/42832/meaning/m0u/) with a little つ.